# Dynamic Controllers in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am in the process of creating a new website which loads all master and child categories from the database. I have tested the navigation as well, i.e., if I click any master category, it perfectly loads all the respective child categories without any issue. However, at present, I am doing this by passing query string in the URL. For instance

```
http://localhost/MyController?id=32145
```

Let's assume that the id, 32145, represents a master category namely '**About us**'. My question is how can I change the above URL to something like:

```
http://localhost/Aboutus
```

and if there is any child category under **About us** than it should display as:

```
http://localhost/Aboutus/Mission
```

Please help me out as I am really stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

by default CodeIgniter uses a segment-based approach, you can do URL routing in way like your second part of the question - "and if there is any child category under About us"

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "catalog/product_lookup";
```

more here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

but if you want to rewrite complete URL than you should probably check .htaccess rewriting

Comment: If i need to dynamically create path $route['product/(:any)'] to say $route['db_value/(:any)']. Than what is to be done?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy, do once for migration.

1. In database you can store the New controller/url for products (if it is not have yet)
2. Create new Controllers
3. Route controller which redirect the old Url to the New Url
   controllers
4. Route old urls to Route controller

Route controller something like this:

```
    public function old_url($aProdId) {
        if (is_null($aProdId)) {
            // error cannot be null
        }

        $NewUrl = $this->new_url_model->getNewUrl($aProdId);

        if (!$NewUrl) {
            // error new url not exist
            return;
        }
        redirect(base_url($NewUrl), 'refresh');
    }
```